# obtain service call using Selenium C# when clicking WebElement

Tags: c#, selenium

I need to intercept service request when selenium clicks on webelement on the page.

Either one of highlighted text (see screenshot)

[image: screenshot of what i need to retrieve]

I don't have capability of installing additional external libraries. Is there any way to use JavascriptExecutor or something else to obtain that service call?

Language: C#

Comment: What do you mean by "intercepting" it? Do you need to check its data and let it run, stop it from running, or construct similar URL?

Comment: @Kiril S, I need to capture highlighted information and put into a variable as a string.